# Shopify Liquid Filter to insert SVG file straight in HTML?

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

Is there a filter to stick an SVG file right in the HTML of a Liquid file? I want to be able to manipulate the SVG styling with CSS, which I am unable to do if I only set the `SRC` of an `IMG`.

For example, is something like this possible with Shopify Liquid:

```
{{ 'file.svg' | file_url | svg_filter }}
```

compiles to

```
<svg>blablalba</svg>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend instead that you put all of your svgs into one liquid snippet file like this:

```
<!-- snippets/icon.liquid -->
<span class="icon icon-{{ icon }}" aria-hidden="true">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {%- if title != blank %}aria-label="{{ title }}"{% endif %} role="img" width="{{ size | default: 16 }}px" height="{{ size | default: 16 }}px" viewBox="{{ viewbox | default: '0 0 16 16' }}">
    {%- case icon -%}
      {%- when 'down' -%}
        <path class="stroke" d="M11.25 6.75l-3.5 3.5-3.5-3.5"/>
      {%- when 'chevron' -%}
        <path class="stroke" d="M1 0l7.875 8L1 16"/>
      {%- when 'location' -%}
        <g class="fill">
          <path d="M8 4.23c-.919 0-1.667.725-1.667 1.616 0 .89.748 1.616 1.667 1.616s1.667-.725 1.667-1.616c0-.89-.748-1.615-1.667-1.615zM8 7c-.656 0-1.19-.518-1.19-1.154 0-.636.534-1.154 1.19-1.154.656 0 1.191.518 1.191 1.154C9.191 6.482 8.656 7 8.001 7z"/>
          <path d="M11.537 2.436A5.022 5.022 0 0 0 8 1c-1.337 0-2.592.51-3.537 1.436C2.717 4.15 2.5 7.373 3.994 9.327L8.001 15l4-5.665c1.5-1.962 1.283-5.185-.464-6.899zm.04 6.6l-3.576 5.066L4.417 9.03c-1.355-1.773-1.161-4.684.416-6.231a4.5 4.5 0 0 1 3.168-1.286 4.5 4.5 0 0 1 3.167 1.286c1.577 1.547 1.772 4.458.41 6.238z"/>
        </g>
      {%- when 'phone' -%}
        <path class="fill" d="M12.555 15.5c-.626 0-1.38-.158-2.207-.47-1.818-.685-3.793-2.037-5.567-3.811C3.007 9.446 1.652 7.467.967 5.652.344 3.999.344 2.642.965 2.02c.089-.089.18-.185.274-.283C1.805 1.142 2.445.47 3.293.5c.586.025 1.153.389 1.732 1.111 1.714 2.13.94 2.892.046 3.771l-.157.158c-.145.145-.424.823 2.15 3.394.838.84 1.555 1.454 2.126 1.826.36.234 1.005.588 1.269.325l.16-.16c.879-.894 1.638-1.663 3.768.05.722.58 1.087 1.145 1.109 1.731.035.847-.64 1.49-1.237 2.056-.098.094-.194.185-.283.274-.308.308-.8.463-1.421.463zM3.234 1.006c-.604 0-1.148.571-1.631 1.079-.096.103-.19.202-.283.293-.461.463-.414 1.678.12 3.097.66 1.75 1.973 3.665 3.698 5.387 1.724 1.724 3.636 3.037 5.387 3.697 1.419.535 2.633.582 3.094.119.094-.092.192-.185.294-.282.52-.492 1.105-1.051 1.08-1.67-.017-.426-.327-.881-.921-1.359-1.773-1.426-2.27-.924-3.094-.089l-.162.163c-.395.394-1.032.308-1.9-.256-.603-.392-1.344-1.03-2.209-1.892C4.571 7.157 3.89 5.852 4.557 5.18l.162-.157c.838-.823 1.342-1.32-.086-3.097-.478-.593-.936-.904-1.36-.92h-.04z"/>
...
```

Then you can call it like this:

`{% render 'icon' with 'down' %}`

Which is the equivalent of calling it like this:

`{% render 'icon', icon: 'down' %}`

Comment: Pretty nifty, using a snippet with optional parameters seems like the best alternative at this point. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

Nope there is no filter but you can "hack" it to show it's html.

If you make a fetch request to the SVG url and it will return it's contents and you can append the content on your page.

While this is not a great solution it's something.

Example:

```
fetch('the_svg_url')
  .then(r=>r.text())
  .then(r => document.querySelector('.svg-holder').innerHTML = r);
```

Comment: If you have html of your svg file, then create a snippet and paste your html in there, and now just use include {% include 'snippet-file' %}, that's it. Then inspect element and change css as per your requirement.

Comment: @user3337667 a snippet is actually a pretty smart way to do it. I wanted to to mostly use a file uploaded to Shopify, but using a snippet would still keep things pretty clean.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below to add svg images into liquid files.

1. Upload the svg file to the theme
2. Use the below code to output the img tag point to the svg file.

`{{ 'file.svg' | asset_url | img_tag }}`

Comment: That sticks an `<img>` in the body, right? This question was for the case where you don't want an `<img>` and instead want `<svg>` tags directly in the body, so that CSS can change how the SVG looks.

Comment: Yes, you are right. My mistake. I misunderstood what you needed.

Comment: This is actually correct, I'm not sure why you are being downvoted.  Open the theme's code editor, upload the image to the `assets` folder and use `{{ 'file.svg' | asset_url }}` to get the absolute path without the `<img/>` tag.