# How to Uglify Javascript with Liquid inline(s) - Shopify

Tags: typescript, gulp, shopify, uglifyjs, gulp-uglify

So today I learnt that minimising JavaScript inside of js.liquid file is a nightmare.

I'm building with `gulp` & `typescript`:

This is a call from my entry TypeScript file that uses a liquid inline:

```js
ajaxLoader("{{ 'logo_black.svg' | asset_url }}")
```

This is module for `ajaxLoader`

```js
 export function ajaxLoader ( URI : string | URL ) : XMLHttpRequest {

    let ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open( "GET", URI, true );
        ajax.send();
        ajax.onload = (e : any) => {
            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let doc = parser.parseFromString( ajax.responseText, "image/svg+xml" );
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(doc.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]);
        };

    
    return ajax;

 }
```

One of my tasks is as follows:

```js
function typescript ( done ) {

    let $browserify = browserify({
            entries : paths.entry
        })
        .plugin(tsify, _typescriptConfig)
            .on("error", log)
        .bundle()
            .on("error", log)
        .pipe(source("theme.js"))
            .on("error", log)
        .pipe(buffer())
            .on("error", log)
        .pipe($.uglify())
            .on("error", log)
        .pipe($.rename((path) => {
            path.extname = ".js.liquid";
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build))
    ;

    done();
}
```

This runs with no errors and builds the file, nice and ugly. However when it comes to the Shopify CLI to sync asset folders, it finds a `{{` in the now minimised file and gives this error:

```
XX:XX:XX ERROR  » update assets/theme.js.liquid:
  Liquid syntax error (line 1): Variable '{{var t=r,i=l,n=e,s=a.slice(1);const o=i[n]||{}' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\}\}/
```

Is there a (local development side) way to work around this that will still allow me to uglify the file, or will I have to do all liquid calls inside inline script tags on the required page?

Or Am I better just using [Hydrogen](https://shopify.dev/api/storefront)

[This article has no help whatsoever](https://community.shopify.com/c/shopify-design/minify-javascript-grunt-uglify/td-p/299213)

Comment: While it doesn't answer the initial premise of the question. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60176599/shopify-liquid-filter-to-insert-svg-file-straight-in-html) does achieve the same things I want to achieve so I will leave it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the your javascript into a `.js` file in assets folder, and then import it back with [url filter](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/filters/url-filters).

Comment: Could you elaborate on how one would achieve that?

Comment: I mean that if you use your javacript in `.js` extension file, you won't be contrained of using {{. So I usually push the javascript in a `.js` file in the assets folder, and import them to your original file with url filter, ex: `{{ "__your_js_file_name__" | asset_url | script_tag }}`

Comment: But what I want is to be able to use the liquid inline within my JS file. This works by itself, but when Uglify processes it the Shopify CLI fires up errors. Due to the nature of TypeScript transpiling and browserify bundling modules, this would result in `{{}}` being on the same one line due to minifcation.

Comment: In that case, I also don't have any solution. One of the workaround I used to do is to encode all the {{, }}, {% and %} in the js file, manually take the data back, decode and eval. Highly not recommended.