# Shopify Liquid Switch Statement Half Working...?

Tags: html, svg, switch-statement, shopify, liquid

Thanks to [@GeorgeButter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1645925/georgebutter) for [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60201308/1473559). I have applied it to my application, however have run into some problems.

I'm having a little issue with finding out why my `case` statement wont load the SVG content.

Below is the code that I have a added in the `Snippets` folder.

```
<!-- snippets/icon.liquid -->
<div class="icon icon-{{- icon | strip | strip_newlines -}}">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {%- if icon != blank %}aria-label="{{- icon | strip | strip_newlines -}}"{% endif %} role="img" width="{{ size | default: 30 }}px" height="{{ size | default: 30 }}px" viewBox="{{ viewbox | default: '0 0 30 30' }}">
    {%- case icon -%}
      {%- when 'fabric' -%}
        <g>
          <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m40.3566 22.3591c13.4123-9.346 28.6444-9.1866 37.0576-.7744l.0183.0186 38.0005 39.001c.026.0271.051.0549.076.0834 3.99 4.5877 7.934 16.7303-3.443 31.0561-11.099 13.9762-25.2466 12.6482-31.7294 9.8782-.6984-.298-1.2756-.733-1.7414-1.204l-40.7343-41.2137c-1.2041-1.2183-1.9027-2.966-1.6436-4.7993 1.3849-9.7968 7.2939-17.0397 13.8077-20.8001 3.2531-1.878 6.739-2.9351 9.9719-2.9446 3.2474-.0096 6.3448 1.0501 8.5083 3.5226 2.2386 2.5584 2.6604 5.5605 1.9955 8.3644-.6461 2.7248-2.3038 5.2654-4.2498 7.2798-1.9487 2.017-4.3395 3.6655-6.66 4.5001-2.2111.7953-5.0394 1.0527-7.0052-.913-1.1793-1.1794-1.8525-2.5197-2.0727-3.9289-.2162-1.3832.0234-2.7016.4506-3.8468.8365-2.2427 2.4958-4.1088 3.7445-5.1654.8432-.7134 2.1051-.6083 2.8186.2349.7135.8433.6083 2.1052-.2349 2.8187-.918.7768-2.0587 2.1107-2.5805 3.5097-.252.6756-.3311 1.2885-.2463 1.8312.0808.5169.3285 1.0975.9492 1.7181.2842.2843 1.0809.6041 2.8229-.0224 1.6327-.5873 3.5232-1.845 5.137-3.5155 1.6164-1.6731 2.8025-3.6013 3.2346-5.4234.4133-1.743.1476-3.3659-1.1138-4.8075-1.2262-1.4013-3.1011-2.1637-5.4862-2.1567-2.3997.0071-5.2065.8055-7.9838 2.4089-5.5471 3.2023-10.6497 9.4257-11.8469 17.8957-.0655.4629.1017.9965.5278 1.4276l40.7343 41.2137c.1727.1747.3313.2795.4681.338 5.2288 2.2339 17.2985 3.5609 27.0258-8.6878 10.179-12.8186 6.268-22.7786 3.592-25.9036l-37.9491-38.9484c-6.5896-6.5779-19.5211-7.4127-31.9334 1.2366-15.1335 10.5455-21.6087 25.9053-27.3802 41.6228-.2687.7317-.082 1.5577.4825 2.108l35.7093 34.8163c.0022.002.0039.004.0051.005.0059.001.0234.002.0506-.005.0314-.008.0588-.023.0776-.04.0153-.013.0271-.029.0361-.055 1.7117-4.9295 4.9881-12.3799 9.519-16.5622.8116-.7492 2.0769-.6986 2.8261.113s.6986 2.077-.113 2.8262c-3.7483 3.46-6.7654 10.074-8.4534 14.935-.9493 2.734-4.5286 3.804-6.7405 1.647l-35.7093-34.8163c-1.6873-1.6451-2.2602-4.1305-1.4449-6.3508 5.7772-15.7332 12.595-32.2002 28.8481-43.5258z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000" class=""></path>
        </g>
      {%- when 'haberdashery' -%}
        <g>
          <g fill="rgb(0,0,0)">
            <path d="m89.6437 15.2722c5.627-4.7957 13.9943-4.4625 19.2223.7654 1.659 1.6585 1.556 4.3775-.223 5.906l-33.8397 29.0732c-.8378.7199-2.1005.6242-2.8203-.2136s-.6242-2.1005.2137-2.8204l33.8393-29.0733c.004-.0035.006-.0063.006-.0063l.002-.0022c.001-.0018.002-.0063.002-.0129.001-.0066-.001-.0111-.001-.013l-.001-.0023s-.002-.0029-.006-.0068c-3.753-3.753-9.7602-3.9922-13.7997-.5494l-35.441 30.2054c-.8407.7165-2.103.6158-2.8195-.2249-.7165-.8406-.6158-2.1029.2249-2.8194z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m55.5 61.9998c-1.1046 0-2 .8955-2 2 0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2h1.5c1.1046 0 2-.8954 2-2 0-1.1045-.8954-2-2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m21.5 38.4998c-2.9221 0-6.2483 1.0103-8.8797 3.13-2.68608 2.1639-4.6203 5.4711-4.6203 9.87 0 6.2894 4.0493 10.2061 6.6954 11.7999.8919.5373 1.8542.7001 2.6831.7001h25.748c.5936 0 1.1565.2637 1.5364.7197l.3284.394-25.5331 24.0087c-4.5981 4.3236-4.9743 11.5018-.8531 16.2828 4.2456 4.925 11.6777 5.481 16.6092 1.243l18.8636-16.2109c3.9726-3.4139 4.2019-9.4859.4981-13.1897l-.1618-.1618c-.781-.781-2.0474-.781-2.8284 0-.7811.7811-.7811 2.0474 0 2.8285l.1618.1617c2.0576 2.0577 1.9302 5.431-.2767 7.3277l-18.8636 16.2105c-3.2579 2.8-8.1678 2.433-10.9726-.821-2.7225-3.1581-2.474-7.9004.5636-10.7567l25.3583-23.8444 2.2076 2.6491c1.1399 1.3679 2.8286 2.1588 4.6093 2.1588h51.1265c7.732 0 14-6.268 14-14 0-2.2091-1.791-4-4-4h-56.6045c-.5998 0-1.168-.2692-1.5479-.7335l-2.0994-2.5659c-1.1387-1.3918-2.8405-2.2006-4.6414-2.2006h-13.1074c-.9877 0-2.1363-.8906-2.7015-2.5761-2.2064-6.58-8.8388-8.4239-13.2979-8.4239zm-9.5 13c0-3.101 1.3158-5.2938 3.1297-6.7549 1.8686-1.5053 4.2924-2.2451 6.3703-2.2451 3.7856 0 8.117 1.555 9.5054 5.6956.8395 2.5036 3.0635 5.3044 6.494 5.3044h13.1074c.5986 0 1.1649.2683 1.5456.7336l2.0994 2.5659c1.1395 1.3928 2.8441 2.2005 4.6437 2.2005h56.6045c0 5.5229-4.477 10-10 10h-51.1265c-.5936 0-1.1565-.2636-1.5364-.7196l-5.1013-6.1215c-1.1399-1.3679-2.8286-2.1589-4.6093-2.1589h-25.748c-.3286 0-.5196-.0665-.6193-.1265-1.9189-1.1558-4.7592-3.9636-4.7592-8.3735z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000" class=""></path>
          </g>
        </g>
      {%- when 'patternsbooks' -%}
        <g>
          <g fill="rgb(0,0,0)">
            <path d="m53.6807 29.9089c-.494-.7585-1.4358-1.0907-2.2964-.8099l-3.2203 1.0508c-1.0501.3427-1.6236 1.4717-1.2809 2.5218.3426 1.0501 1.4717 1.6235 2.5217 1.2809l1.8665-.6091c.5148.6066 1.1427 1.25 1.8728 1.8825.8348.7233 2.0979.6328 2.8212-.202s.6329-2.0979-.202-2.8212c-1.013-.8777-1.7138-1.7275-2.0826-2.2938z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m77.6157 29.099c-.8606-.2808-1.8024.0514-2.2964.8099-.3688.5663-1.0696 1.4161-2.0826 2.2938-.8349.7233-.9253 1.9864-.202 2.8212s1.9864.9253 2.8212.202c.7301-.6325 1.358-1.2759 1.8728-1.8825l1.8665.6091c1.05.3426 2.1791-.2308 2.5217-1.2809.3427-1.0501-.2308-2.1791-1.2809-2.5218z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m42.9641 36.0542c1.0501-.3427 1.6236-1.4717 1.2809-2.5218-.3426-1.0501-1.4717-1.6236-2.5217-1.2809l-3.2204 1.0508c-.8049.2627-1.5794.5962-2.3152.994-.9717.5253-1.3335 1.7389-.8082 2.7105.5254.9717 1.7389 1.3335 2.7106.8082.5255-.2842 1.0786-.5223 1.6537-.71z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87.2767 32.2515c-1.05-.3427-2.1791.2308-2.5217 1.2809-.3427 1.0501.2308 2.1791 1.2809 2.5218l3.2203 1.0508c.5751.1877 1.1282.4258 1.6537.71.9717.5253 2.1852.1635 2.7106-.8082.5253-.9716.1635-2.1852-.8082-2.7105-.7358-.3978-1.5103-.7313-2.3152-.994z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m68.6303 39.0709c1.0694-.2765 1.7121-1.3676 1.4356-2.437s-1.3675-1.7122-2.4369-1.4357c-.9701.2509-2.0144.3978-3.129.3978s-2.1589-.1469-3.129-.3978c-1.0694-.2765-2.1604.3663-2.4369 1.4357s.3662 2.1605 1.4356 2.437c1.2797.3309 2.6604.5251 4.1303.5251s2.8506-.1942 4.1303-.5251z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m35.2933 40.0575c.7239-.8343.6345-2.0974-.1997-2.8214s-2.0974-.6346-2.8214.1997c-.5483.6318-1.042 1.3152-1.4734 2.0438l-2.255 3.809c-.5627.9505-.2483 2.1772.7022 2.7399s2.1772.2483 2.7399-.7022l2.2549-3.809c.3082-.5205.6609-1.0086 1.0525-1.4598z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m96.7278 37.4358c-.724-.8343-1.9872-.9237-2.8214-.1997s-.9236 1.9871-.1997 2.8214c.3916.4512.7443.9393 1.0525 1.4598l2.2549 3.809c.5627.9505 1.7894 1.2649 2.7399.7022.95-.5627 1.265-1.7894.702-2.7399l-2.2548-3.809c-.4313-.7286-.9251-1.412-1.4734-2.0438z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m27.476 52.9442c.5627-.9505.2483-2.1771-.7022-2.7398s-2.1772-.2484-2.7399.7021l-2.2549 3.809c-.309.5218-.3644 1.1556-.1509 1.7232.2136.5676.6731 1.0076 1.2495 1.1963l1.1958.3916c.4531.1484.9211.1261 1.3344-.0316.2399.3716.6041.6665 1.0572.8149l1.1959.3916c1.0497.3438 2.1793-.2285 2.5231-1.2782s-.2285-2.1794-1.2782-2.5231l-1.1959-.3917c-.4531-.1484-.9211-.1261-1.3344.0317-.024-.0372-.0492-.0736-.0757-.1092z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m104.966 50.9065c-.563-.9505-1.789-1.2648-2.74-.7021-.95.5627-1.265 1.7893-.702 2.7398l1.176 1.9868c-.026.0356-.052.072-.076.1092-.413-.1578-.881-.1801-1.334-.0317l-1.196.3917c-1.0495.3437-1.6218 1.4734-1.278 2.5231s1.473 1.622 2.523 1.2782l1.196-.3916c.453-.1484.817-.4433 1.057-.8149.413.1577.881.18 1.335.0316l1.195-.3916c.577-.1887 1.036-.6287 1.25-1.1963.213-.5676.158-1.2014-.151-1.7232z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 63.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v3.3333c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 63.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v3.3333c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 73.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1045.8954 2 2 2s2-.8955 2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 73.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1045.8954 2 2 2s2-.8955 2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 86.3336c0-1.1045-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8955-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 86.3336c0-1.1045-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8955-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 99.667c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v3.333c0 1.105.8954 2 2 2h3.4167c1.1045 0 2-.895 2-2 0-1.104-.8955-2-2-2h-1.4167z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 99.667c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v1.333h-1.4167c-1.1045 0-2 .896-2 2 0 1.105.8955 2 2 2h3.4167c1.1046 0 2-.895 2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m54.25 101c-1.1046 0-2 .896-2 2 0 1.105.8954 2 2 2h6.8333c1.1046 0 2-.895 2-2 0-1.104-.8954-2-2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m67.9167 101c-1.1046 0-2 .896-2 2 0 1.105.8954 2 2 2h6.8333c1.1046 0 2-.895 2-2 0-1.104-.8954-2-2-2z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000"></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m78.7476 18.0365c.4825-.8773 1.5393-1.2626 2.4732-.9018l17.6684 6.8264c3.2518 1.2563 5.9178 3.6804 7.4768 6.7982l12.423 24.8466c.252.5035.28 1.0899.077 1.6151-.203.5251-.618.9405-1.143 1.144l-23.223 9.0049v44.6301h-60v-44.6301l-23.2231-9.0049c-.5249-.2035-.9397-.6189-1.1425-1.144-.20291-.5252-.17503-1.1116.0767-1.6151l12.4233-24.8466c1.5589-3.1178 4.2249-5.5419 7.4764-6.7982l17.6684-6.8264c.9339-.3608 1.9907.0245 2.4732.9018.7905 1.4372 2.5123 3.7202 5.001 5.6258 2.4723 1.8931 5.5979 3.338 9.2466 3.338s6.7743-1.4449 9.2466-3.338c2.4887-1.9056 4.2105-4.1886 5.001-5.6258zm11.7524 48.0105c-.0007-.0309-.0007-.0617 0-.0924v-9.9543c0-1.1046.8954-2 2-2s2 .8954 2 2v7.0794l19.729-7.6499-11.441-22.8816c-1.114-2.227-3.0179-3.9585-5.3404-4.8559l-16.1279-6.2312c-1.1633 1.6829-2.9004 3.6613-5.1413 5.3772-2.9693 2.2736-6.9271 4.162-11.6784 4.162s-8.7091-1.8884-11.6784-4.162c-2.2409-1.7159-3.978-3.6943-5.1413-5.3772l-16.1279 6.2312c-2.3225.8974-4.2268 2.6289-5.3403 4.8559l-11.4408 22.8816 19.7287 7.6499v-7.0794c0-1.1046.8954-2 2-2s2 .8954 2 2v9.9543c.0007.0307.0007.0615 0 .0924v41.953h52z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000"></path>
          </g>
        </g>
      {%- when 'giftcards' -%}
        <g>
          <g fill="rgb(0,0,0)">
            <g clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m20 75c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h2c.5523 0 1 .4477 1 1v14c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h36c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-14c0-.5523.4477-1 1-1h2c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-14c0-.5523-.4477-1-1-1h-44c-.5523 0-1 .4477-1 1zm5-11c-.5523 0-1 .4477-1 1v6c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h2c.5523 0 1 .4477 1 1v14c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h28c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-14c0-.5523.4477-1 1-1h2c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-6c0-.5523-.4477-1-1-1z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m45 88v-24h-4v24zm4 4h-12v-32h12z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m38.6777 52.0305c1.6851 2.493 2.357 6.6985 2.357 9.9925h4c0-3.5395-.6782-8.7339-3.0431-12.2326-1.2285-1.8176-3.0158-3.3189-5.4874-3.6989-2.4225-.3724-5.1076.3957-8.0352 2.239-.0358.0226-.0709.0463-.1053.0711-1.8313 1.3226-3.9833 4.1454-3.203 7.5327.7865 3.4142 4.2798 6.1709 10.8325 8.0139l1.083-3.8506c-6.2473-1.7571-7.754-3.917-8.0176-5.0611-.266-1.1549.458-2.5103 1.5991-3.3571 2.4414-1.5251 4.1261-1.8054 5.2387-1.6344 1.0721.1649 1.9849.8072 2.7813 1.9855z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m47.357 52.0305c-1.6851 2.493-2.357 6.6985-2.357 9.9925h-4c0-3.5395.6781-8.7339 3.043-12.2326 1.2286-1.8176 3.0158-3.3189 5.4875-3.6989 2.4224-.3724 5.1075.3957 8.0351 2.239.0359.0226.071.0463.1054.0711 1.8313 1.3226 3.9832 4.1454 3.203 7.5327-.7865 3.4142-4.2798 6.1709-10.8325 8.0139l-1.083-3.8506c6.2473-1.7571 7.754-3.917 8.0175-5.0611.2661-1.1549-.4579-2.5103-1.599-3.3571-2.4414-1.5251-4.1261-1.8054-5.2387-1.6344-1.0721.1649-1.9849.8072-2.7813 1.9855z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g><path d="m17 30c-2.2091 0-4 1.7909-4 4v60c0 2.2091 1.7909 4 4 4h94c2.209 0 4-1.7909 4-4v-5.5l4 4v1.5c0 4.4183-3.582 8-8 8h-94c-4.4183 0-8-3.5817-8-8v-60c0-4.4183 3.5817-8 8-8h36.5l3.5 4z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m115 34c0-2.2091-1.791-4-4-4h-39l-4-4h43c4.418 0 8 3.5817 8 8v43l-4-4z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m66.8434 28h-9.7331l18.3733 18.5-.9834 4.6862-23.614-23.7769c-1.2532-1.2619-.3594-3.4093 1.4191-3.4093h15.3665c.5304 0 1.0391.2107 1.4142.5858l15.9142 15.9142-3 2.6569z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m116 87.296v-10.1391l-15.157-15.1569 2.657-3 15.914 15.9142c.375.3751.586.8838.586 1.4142v15.8196c0 1.7851-2.161 2.676-3.419 1.4094l-23.8924-24.0574 4.8116-.8315z" fill="#000000" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m73.0002 49.373c0 .2652-.1053.5195-.2928.7071l-5.2132 5.2131c-.3905.3905-.3905 1.0237 0 1.4142l5.2132 5.2132c.1875.1875.2928.4418.2928.7071v7.3726c0 .5523.4478 1 1 1h7.3727c.2652 0 .5196.1054.7071.2929l5.2132 5.2132c.3905.3905 1.0237.3905 1.4142 0l5.2132-5.2132c.1876-.1875.4419-.2929.7071-.2929h7.3723c.553 0 1-.4477 1-1v-7.3725c0-.2652.106-.5196.293-.7071l5.213-5.2133c.391-.3905.391-1.0237 0-1.4142l-5.213-5.2133c-.187-.1875-.293-.4419-.293-.7071v-7.3725c0-.5523-.447-1-1-1h-7.3723c-.2652 0-.5195-.1053-.7071-.2929l-5.2132-5.2132c-.3905-.3905-1.0237-.3905-1.4142 0l-5.2132 5.2132c-.1875.1876-.4419.2929-.7071.2929h-7.3727c-.5522 0-1 .4477-1 1zm5-4.3727c-.5522 0-1 .4477-1 1v5.0295c0 .2652-.1053.5196-.2928.7071l-3.5563 3.5563c-.3906.3905-.3906 1.0237 0 1.4142l3.5563 3.5563c.1875.1875.2928.4419.2928.7071v5.0295c0 .5523.4478 1 1 1h5.0296c.2652 0 .5195.1054.7071.2929l3.5563 3.5564c.3905.3905 1.0237.3905 1.4142 0l3.5564-3.5564c.1875-.1875.4419-.2929.7071-.2929h5.0293c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-5.0294c0-.2652.1054-.5195.2929-.7071l3.5569-3.5564c.39-.3905.39-1.0237 0-1.4142l-3.5569-3.5564c-.1875-.1875-.2929-.4419-.2929-.7071v-5.0294c0-.5523-.4477-1-1-1h-5.0293c-.2652 0-.5196-.1053-.7071-.2929l-3.5564-3.5563c-.3905-.3906-1.0237-.3906-1.4142 0l-3.5563 3.5563c-.1876.1876-.4419.2929-.7071.2929z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000" class=""></path>
          </g>
        </g>
    {%- endcase -%}
   </svg>
</div>
```

From there I have created a code to dynamically `render` the icon SVG based on the `variable`. The variable is based on the menu items title.

```
{% for link in section.settings.link_list.links %}
    {% capture icon %}
    {{ link.title | downcase | replace: " ", "" | remove: "&" }}
    {% endcapture %}

    {% render 'icon', icon: icon %}
    
    <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
        {{ link.title }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I seem to receive the correct output, as the class in the SVG file is loaded with the link title, its just the `case` code doesn't seem to render the SVG content?

[image: Description]

Comment: issue is with word letter in liquid Fabric and into case fabric, it need to be same case to work properly

Comment: @Onkar The issue seems to originate from the `icon` itself. It was outputting the correct word, however it contained whitespace, meaning that the word `fabric` was appearing correctly, just with a space on each side. `case` was not working as it was looking for the exact word, without whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is solved by a simple technique of *debugging*. Use the common HTML *comment* to establish your test condition or case makes sense. I am pretty sure you will surprise yourself here. Here is that secret sauce:

```
<!-- Secret here >>> {{icon | strip | strip_newlines}} -->
```

You can run your code, and then search the generated source for *Secret*. When you see what the Liquid parse generated, you will have proof of the test conditions to use to test with in your **case** statements. That case/when test is **exact** whereas your **if** statement approach is *loose*, using **contains**.

Once you know why your test condition works loosely, maybe you'll see the pattern where you could flip back to using the more precise case.

Comment: So I have done as you suggested. When outputting the `{{ icon }}` alone, it would return `<span> fabric </span>`, suggesting that the icon title had whitespace along both ends. I have since updated my code to `{% assign icon = icon | strip %}` prior to the `case` statement and it *seems to have worked!*

Your help in resolving this issue is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So after many attempts at using `case`, I decided to try an alternative method - and **it worked!** It isn't *too* much longer, but here it is.

```
<!-- snippets/icon.liquid -->
<div class="icon icon-{{- icon | strip | strip_newlines -}}">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {%- if icon != blank %}aria-label="{{- icon | strip | strip_newlines -}}"{% endif %} width="{{ size | default: 128 }}" height="{{ size | default: 128 }}" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 128 128">
    {%- if icon contains 'fabric' -%}
      <g><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m40.3566 22.3591c13.4123-9.346 28.6444-9.1866 37.0576-.7744l.0183.0186 38.0005 39.001c.026.0271.051.0549.076.0834 3.99 4.5877 7.934 16.7303-3.443 31.0561-11.099 13.9762-25.2466 12.6482-31.7294 9.8782-.6984-.298-1.2756-.733-1.7414-1.204l-40.7343-41.2137c-1.2041-1.2183-1.9027-2.966-1.6436-4.7993 1.3849-9.7968 7.2939-17.0397 13.8077-20.8001 3.2531-1.878 6.739-2.9351 9.9719-2.9446 3.2474-.0096 6.3448 1.0501 8.5083 3.5226 2.2386 2.5584 2.6604 5.5605 1.9955 8.3644-.6461 2.7248-2.3038 5.2654-4.2498 7.2798-1.9487 2.017-4.3395 3.6655-6.66 4.5001-2.2111.7953-5.0394 1.0527-7.0052-.913-1.1793-1.1794-1.8525-2.5197-2.0727-3.9289-.2162-1.3832.0234-2.7016.4506-3.8468.8365-2.2427 2.4958-4.1088 3.7445-5.1654.8432-.7134 2.1051-.6083 2.8186.2349.7135.8433.6083 2.1052-.2349 2.8187-.918.7768-2.0587 2.1107-2.5805 3.5097-.252.6756-.3311 1.2885-.2463 1.8312.0808.5169.3285 1.0975.9492 1.7181.2842.2843 1.0809.6041 2.8229-.0224 1.6327-.5873 3.5232-1.845 5.137-3.5155 1.6164-1.6731 2.8025-3.6013 3.2346-5.4234.4133-1.743.1476-3.3659-1.1138-4.8075-1.2262-1.4013-3.1011-2.1637-5.4862-2.1567-2.3997.0071-5.2065.8055-7.9838 2.4089-5.5471 3.2023-10.6497 9.4257-11.8469 17.8957-.0655.4629.1017.9965.5278 1.4276l40.7343 41.2137c.1727.1747.3313.2795.4681.338 5.2288 2.2339 17.2985 3.5609 27.0258-8.6878 10.179-12.8186 6.268-22.7786 3.592-25.9036l-37.9491-38.9484c-6.5896-6.5779-19.5211-7.4127-31.9334 1.2366-15.1335 10.5455-21.6087 25.9053-27.3802 41.6228-.2687.7317-.082 1.5577.4825 2.108l35.7093 34.8163c.0022.002.0039.004.0051.005.0059.001.0234.002.0506-.005.0314-.008.0588-.023.0776-.04.0153-.013.0271-.029.0361-.055 1.7117-4.9295 4.9881-12.3799 9.519-16.5622.8116-.7492 2.0769-.6986 2.8261.113s.6986 2.077-.113 2.8262c-3.7483 3.46-6.7654 10.074-8.4534 14.935-.9493 2.734-4.5286 3.804-6.7405 1.647l-35.7093-34.8163c-1.6873-1.6451-2.2602-4.1305-1.4449-6.3508 5.7772-15.7332 12.595-32.2002 28.8481-43.5258z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g>
    {%- elsif icon contains 'haberdashery' -%}
      <g><g><path d="m89.6437 15.2722c5.627-4.7957 13.9943-4.4625 19.2223.7654 1.659 1.6585 1.556 4.3775-.223 5.906l-33.8397 29.0732c-.8378.7199-2.1005.6242-2.8203-.2136s-.6242-2.1005.2137-2.8204l33.8393-29.0733c.004-.0035.006-.0063.006-.0063l.002-.0022c.001-.0018.002-.0063.002-.0129.001-.0066-.001-.0111-.001-.013l-.001-.0023s-.002-.0029-.006-.0068c-3.753-3.753-9.7602-3.9922-13.7997-.5494l-35.441 30.2054c-.8407.7165-2.103.6158-2.8195-.2249-.7165-.8406-.6158-2.1029.2249-2.8194z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m55.5 61.9998c-1.1046 0-2 .8955-2 2 0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2h1.5c1.1046 0 2-.8954 2-2 0-1.1045-.8954-2-2-2z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m21.5 38.4998c-2.9221 0-6.2483 1.0103-8.8797 3.13-2.68608 2.1639-4.6203 5.4711-4.6203 9.87 0 6.2894 4.0493 10.2061 6.6954 11.7999.8919.5373 1.8542.7001 2.6831.7001h25.748c.5936 0 1.1565.2637 1.5364.7197l.3284.394-25.5331 24.0087c-4.5981 4.3236-4.9743 11.5018-.8531 16.2828 4.2456 4.925 11.6777 5.481 16.6092 1.243l18.8636-16.2109c3.9726-3.4139 4.2019-9.4859.4981-13.1897l-.1618-.1618c-.781-.781-2.0474-.781-2.8284 0-.7811.7811-.7811 2.0474 0 2.8285l.1618.1617c2.0576 2.0577 1.9302 5.431-.2767 7.3277l-18.8636 16.2105c-3.2579 2.8-8.1678 2.433-10.9726-.821-2.7225-3.1581-2.474-7.9004.5636-10.7567l25.3583-23.8444 2.2076 2.6491c1.1399 1.3679 2.8286 2.1588 4.6093 2.1588h51.1265c7.732 0 14-6.268 14-14 0-2.2091-1.791-4-4-4h-56.6045c-.5998 0-1.168-.2692-1.5479-.7335l-2.0994-2.5659c-1.1387-1.3918-2.8405-2.2006-4.6414-2.2006h-13.1074c-.9877 0-2.1363-.8906-2.7015-2.5761-2.2064-6.58-8.8388-8.4239-13.2979-8.4239zm-9.5 13c0-3.101 1.3158-5.2938 3.1297-6.7549 1.8686-1.5053 4.2924-2.2451 6.3703-2.2451 3.7856 0 8.117 1.555 9.5054 5.6956.8395 2.5036 3.0635 5.3044 6.494 5.3044h13.1074c.5986 0 1.1649.2683 1.5456.7336l2.0994 2.5659c1.1395 1.3928 2.8441 2.2005 4.6437 2.2005h56.6045c0 5.5229-4.477 10-10 10h-51.1265c-.5936 0-1.1565-.2636-1.5364-.7196l-5.1013-6.1215c-1.1399-1.3679-2.8286-2.1589-4.6093-2.1589h-25.748c-.3286 0-.5196-.0665-.6193-.1265-1.9189-1.1558-4.7592-3.9636-4.7592-8.3735z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></g>
    {%- elsif icon contains 'patternsbooks' -%}
      <g><g><path d="m53.6807 29.9089c-.494-.7585-1.4358-1.0907-2.2964-.8099l-3.2203 1.0508c-1.0501.3427-1.6236 1.4717-1.2809 2.5218.3426 1.0501 1.4717 1.6235 2.5217 1.2809l1.8665-.6091c.5148.6066 1.1427 1.25 1.8728 1.8825.8348.7233 2.0979.6328 2.8212-.202s.6329-2.0979-.202-2.8212c-1.013-.8777-1.7138-1.7275-2.0826-2.2938z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m77.6157 29.099c-.8606-.2808-1.8024.0514-2.2964.8099-.3688.5663-1.0696 1.4161-2.0826 2.2938-.8349.7233-.9253 1.9864-.202 2.8212s1.9864.9253 2.8212.202c.7301-.6325 1.358-1.2759 1.8728-1.8825l1.8665.6091c1.05.3426 2.1791-.2308 2.5217-1.2809.3427-1.0501-.2308-2.1791-1.2809-2.5218z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m42.9641 36.0542c1.0501-.3427 1.6236-1.4717 1.2809-2.5218-.3426-1.0501-1.4717-1.6236-2.5217-1.2809l-3.2204 1.0508c-.8049.2627-1.5794.5962-2.3152.994-.9717.5253-1.3335 1.7389-.8082 2.7105.5254.9717 1.7389 1.3335 2.7106.8082.5255-.2842 1.0786-.5223 1.6537-.71z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87.2767 32.2515c-1.05-.3427-2.1791.2308-2.5217 1.2809-.3427 1.0501.2308 2.1791 1.2809 2.5218l3.2203 1.0508c.5751.1877 1.1282.4258 1.6537.71.9717.5253 2.1852.1635 2.7106-.8082.5253-.9716.1635-2.1852-.8082-2.7105-.7358-.3978-1.5103-.7313-2.3152-.994z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m68.6303 39.0709c1.0694-.2765 1.7121-1.3676 1.4356-2.437s-1.3675-1.7122-2.4369-1.4357c-.9701.2509-2.0144.3978-3.129.3978s-2.1589-.1469-3.129-.3978c-1.0694-.2765-2.1604.3663-2.4369 1.4357s.3662 2.1605 1.4356 2.437c1.2797.3309 2.6604.5251 4.1303.5251s2.8506-.1942 4.1303-.5251z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m35.2933 40.0575c.7239-.8343.6345-2.0974-.1997-2.8214s-2.0974-.6346-2.8214.1997c-.5483.6318-1.042 1.3152-1.4734 2.0438l-2.255 3.809c-.5627.9505-.2483 2.1772.7022 2.7399s2.1772.2483 2.7399-.7022l2.2549-3.809c.3082-.5205.6609-1.0086 1.0525-1.4598z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m96.7278 37.4358c-.724-.8343-1.9872-.9237-2.8214-.1997s-.9236 1.9871-.1997 2.8214c.3916.4512.7443.9393 1.0525 1.4598l2.2549 3.809c.5627.9505 1.7894 1.2649 2.7399.7022.95-.5627 1.265-1.7894.702-2.7399l-2.2548-3.809c-.4313-.7286-.9251-1.412-1.4734-2.0438z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m27.476 52.9442c.5627-.9505.2483-2.1771-.7022-2.7398s-2.1772-.2484-2.7399.7021l-2.2549 3.809c-.309.5218-.3644 1.1556-.1509 1.7232.2136.5676.6731 1.0076 1.2495 1.1963l1.1958.3916c.4531.1484.9211.1261 1.3344-.0316.2399.3716.6041.6665 1.0572.8149l1.1959.3916c1.0497.3438 2.1793-.2285 2.5231-1.2782s-.2285-2.1794-1.2782-2.5231l-1.1959-.3917c-.4531-.1484-.9211-.1261-1.3344.0317-.024-.0372-.0492-.0736-.0757-.1092z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m104.966 50.9065c-.563-.9505-1.789-1.2648-2.74-.7021-.95.5627-1.265 1.7893-.702 2.7398l1.176 1.9868c-.026.0356-.052.072-.076.1092-.413-.1578-.881-.1801-1.334-.0317l-1.196.3917c-1.0495.3437-1.6218 1.4734-1.278 2.5231s1.473 1.622 2.523 1.2782l1.196-.3916c.453-.1484.817-.4433 1.057-.8149.413.1577.881.18 1.335.0316l1.195-.3916c.577-.1887 1.036-.6287 1.25-1.1963.213-.5676.158-1.2014-.151-1.7232z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 63.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v3.3333c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 63.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v3.3333c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 73.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1045.8954 2 2 2s2-.8955 2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 73.0003c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1045.8954 2 2 2s2-.8955 2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 86.3336c0-1.1045-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8955-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 86.3336c0-1.1045-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8955-2 2v6.6667c0 1.1046.8954 2 2 2s2-.8954 2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m46 99.667c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v3.333c0 1.105.8954 2 2 2h3.4167c1.1045 0 2-.895 2-2 0-1.104-.8955-2-2-2h-1.4167z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m87 99.667c0-1.1046-.8954-2-2-2s-2 .8954-2 2v1.333h-1.4167c-1.1045 0-2 .896-2 2 0 1.105.8955 2 2 2h3.4167c1.1046 0 2-.895 2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m54.25 101c-1.1046 0-2 .896-2 2 0 1.105.8954 2 2 2h6.8333c1.1046 0 2-.895 2-2 0-1.104-.8954-2-2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path d="m67.9167 101c-1.1046 0-2 .896-2 2 0 1.105.8954 2 2 2h6.8333c1.1046 0 2-.895 2-2 0-1.104-.8954-2-2-2z" data-original="#000000"></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m78.7476 18.0365c.4825-.8773 1.5393-1.2626 2.4732-.9018l17.6684 6.8264c3.2518 1.2563 5.9178 3.6804 7.4768 6.7982l12.423 24.8466c.252.5035.28 1.0899.077 1.6151-.203.5251-.618.9405-1.143 1.144l-23.223 9.0049v44.6301h-60v-44.6301l-23.2231-9.0049c-.5249-.2035-.9397-.6189-1.1425-1.144-.20291-.5252-.17503-1.1116.0767-1.6151l12.4233-24.8466c1.5589-3.1178 4.2249-5.5419 7.4764-6.7982l17.6684-6.8264c.9339-.3608 1.9907.0245 2.4732.9018.7905 1.4372 2.5123 3.7202 5.001 5.6258 2.4723 1.8931 5.5979 3.338 9.2466 3.338s6.7743-1.4449 9.2466-3.338c2.4887-1.9056 4.2105-4.1886 5.001-5.6258zm11.7524 48.0105c-.0007-.0309-.0007-.0617 0-.0924v-9.9543c0-1.1046.8954-2 2-2s2 .8954 2 2v7.0794l19.729-7.6499-11.441-22.8816c-1.114-2.227-3.0179-3.9585-5.3404-4.8559l-16.1279-6.2312c-1.1633 1.6829-2.9004 3.6613-5.1413 5.3772-2.9693 2.2736-6.9271 4.162-11.6784 4.162s-8.7091-1.8884-11.6784-4.162c-2.2409-1.7159-3.978-3.6943-5.1413-5.3772l-16.1279 6.2312c-2.3225.8974-4.2268 2.6289-5.3403 4.8559l-11.4408 22.8816 19.7287 7.6499v-7.0794c0-1.1046.8954-2 2-2s2 .8954 2 2v9.9543c.0007.0307.0007.0615 0 .0924v41.953h52z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000"></path></g></g>
    {%- elsif icon contains 'giftcards' -%}
      <g><g><g clip-rule="evenodd" fill-rule="evenodd"><path d="m20 75c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h2c.5523 0 1 .4477 1 1v14c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h36c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-14c0-.5523.4477-1 1-1h2c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-14c0-.5523-.4477-1-1-1h-44c-.5523 0-1 .4477-1 1zm5-11c-.5523 0-1 .4477-1 1v6c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h2c.5523 0 1 .4477 1 1v14c0 .5523.4477 1 1 1h28c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-14c0-.5523.4477-1 1-1h2c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-6c0-.5523-.4477-1-1-1z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m45 88v-24h-4v24zm4 4h-12v-32h12z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m38.6777 52.0305c1.6851 2.493 2.357 6.6985 2.357 9.9925h4c0-3.5395-.6782-8.7339-3.0431-12.2326-1.2285-1.8176-3.0158-3.3189-5.4874-3.6989-2.4225-.3724-5.1076.3957-8.0352 2.239-.0358.0226-.0709.0463-.1053.0711-1.8313 1.3226-3.9833 4.1454-3.203 7.5327.7865 3.4142 4.2798 6.1709 10.8325 8.0139l1.083-3.8506c-6.2473-1.7571-7.754-3.917-8.0176-5.0611-.266-1.1549.458-2.5103 1.5991-3.3571 2.4414-1.5251 4.1261-1.8054 5.2387-1.6344 1.0721.1649 1.9849.8072 2.7813 1.9855z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m47.357 52.0305c-1.6851 2.493-2.357 6.6985-2.357 9.9925h-4c0-3.5395.6781-8.7339 3.043-12.2326 1.2286-1.8176 3.0158-3.3189 5.4875-3.6989 2.4224-.3724 5.1075.3957 8.0351 2.239.0359.0226.071.0463.1054.0711 1.8313 1.3226 3.9832 4.1454 3.203 7.5327-.7865 3.4142-4.2798 6.1709-10.8325 8.0139l-1.083-3.8506c6.2473-1.7571 7.754-3.917 8.0175-5.0611.2661-1.1549-.4579-2.5103-1.599-3.3571-2.4414-1.5251-4.1261-1.8054-5.2387-1.6344-1.0721.1649-1.9849.8072-2.7813 1.9855z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g><path d="m17 30c-2.2091 0-4 1.7909-4 4v60c0 2.2091 1.7909 4 4 4h94c2.209 0 4-1.7909 4-4v-5.5l4 4v1.5c0 4.4183-3.582 8-8 8h-94c-4.4183 0-8-3.5817-8-8v-60c0-4.4183 3.5817-8 8-8h36.5l3.5 4z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m115 34c0-2.2091-1.791-4-4-4h-39l-4-4h43c4.418 0 8 3.5817 8 8v43l-4-4z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m66.8434 28h-9.7331l18.3733 18.5-.9834 4.6862-23.614-23.7769c-1.2532-1.2619-.3594-3.4093 1.4191-3.4093h15.3665c.5304 0 1.0391.2107 1.4142.5858l15.9142 15.9142-3 2.6569z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path d="m116 87.296v-10.1391l-15.157-15.1569 2.657-3 15.914 15.9142c.375.3751.586.8838.586 1.4142v15.8196c0 1.7851-2.161 2.676-3.419 1.4094l-23.8924-24.0574 4.8116-.8315z" data-original="#000000" class=""></path><path clip-rule="evenodd" d="m73.0002 49.373c0 .2652-.1053.5195-.2928.7071l-5.2132 5.2131c-.3905.3905-.3905 1.0237 0 1.4142l5.2132 5.2132c.1875.1875.2928.4418.2928.7071v7.3726c0 .5523.4478 1 1 1h7.3727c.2652 0 .5196.1054.7071.2929l5.2132 5.2132c.3905.3905 1.0237.3905 1.4142 0l5.2132-5.2132c.1876-.1875.4419-.2929.7071-.2929h7.3723c.553 0 1-.4477 1-1v-7.3725c0-.2652.106-.5196.293-.7071l5.213-5.2133c.391-.3905.391-1.0237 0-1.4142l-5.213-5.2133c-.187-.1875-.293-.4419-.293-.7071v-7.3725c0-.5523-.447-1-1-1h-7.3723c-.2652 0-.5195-.1053-.7071-.2929l-5.2132-5.2132c-.3905-.3905-1.0237-.3905-1.4142 0l-5.2132 5.2132c-.1875.1876-.4419.2929-.7071.2929h-7.3727c-.5522 0-1 .4477-1 1zm5-4.3727c-.5522 0-1 .4477-1 1v5.0295c0 .2652-.1053.5196-.2928.7071l-3.5563 3.5563c-.3906.3905-.3906 1.0237 0 1.4142l3.5563 3.5563c.1875.1875.2928.4419.2928.7071v5.0295c0 .5523.4478 1 1 1h5.0296c.2652 0 .5195.1054.7071.2929l3.5563 3.5564c.3905.3905 1.0237.3905 1.4142 0l3.5564-3.5564c.1875-.1875.4419-.2929.7071-.2929h5.0293c.5523 0 1-.4477 1-1v-5.0294c0-.2652.1054-.5195.2929-.7071l3.5569-3.5564c.39-.3905.39-1.0237 0-1.4142l-3.5569-3.5564c-.1875-.1875-.2929-.4419-.2929-.7071v-5.0294c0-.5523-.4477-1-1-1h-5.0293c-.2652 0-.5196-.1053-.7071-.2929l-3.5564-3.5563c-.3905-.3906-1.0237-.3906-1.4142 0l-3.5563 3.5563c-.1876.1876-.4419.2929-.7071.2929z" fill-rule="evenodd" data-original="#000000" class=""></path></g></g>
    {%- endif -%}
   </svg>
</div>
```

It seems to be the only way I have managed to make it work.

I am still curious as to whether using `case` is still possible, so if anyone has more information, it would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:** Streamlined the code as to not replicate the `svg` element multiple times.